# How to make pytube print all available resolutions and the user inputs one

Tags: python, pytube

**Intro:** So I am trying to make a pytube project but I am stuck on this one step,

Problem: I can't figure out how to make pytube list all the available resolutions

---

```
from pytube import YouTube

# import the package
print("Please Paste The URL of the youtube video")
url = input()
# URL (user input)
my_video = YouTube(url)
print(my_video.title)
# Title of The Video

#Now for the Thumbnail Image
print("Thumbnail URL")
print(my_video.thumbnail_url)

#To Download the video with the users Choice of resolution

print("Choose A Resolution Please")
for stream in my_video.stream:
    print(stream)
#command for downloading the video
my_video.download()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an attribute for the stream object that goes by resolution. For example

You have:

```
for stream in my_video.stream:
    print(stream)
```

But since you want to display the resolution of each stream objects, you can try:

```
for stream in my_video.streams:
    print(stream.resolution)
```

(Note this also corrects `my_video.stream` to `my_video.streams`)

I took the time to write a script to test my thought.

```
from pytube import YouTube

def download(video_resolutions, videos):
    while True:
        # Looping through the video_resolutions list to be displayed on the screen for user selection...
        i = 1
        for resolution in video_resolutions:
            print(f'{i}. {resolution}')
            i += 1

        # To Download the video with the users Choice of resolution
        choice = int(input('\nChoose A Resolution Please: '))
        
        # To validate if the user enters a number displayed on the screen...
        if 1 <= choice < i:
            resolution_to_download = video_resolutions[choice - 1]
            print(f"You're now downloading the video with resolution {resolution_to_download}...")

            # command for downloading the video
            videos[choice - 1].download()

            print("\nVideo was successfully downloaded!")
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid choice!!\n\n")


def sort_resolutions(url):
    # URL (user input)
    my_video = YouTube(url)
    print(my_video.title)
    # Title of The Video

    # Now for the Thumbnail Image
    print("Thumbnail URL")
    print(my_video.thumbnail_url)

    video_resolutions = []
    videos = []

    for stream in my_video.streams.order_by('resolution'):
        # print(stream)
        video_resolutions.append(stream.resolution)
        videos.append(stream)

    # print(video_resolutions)

    return video_resolutions, videos


print("Please Paste The URL of the youtube video")
url = "https://youtu.be/o9aaoiyJlcM"

video_resolutions, videos = sort_resolutions(url)

download(video_resolutions, videos)
```

The `url = "https://youtu.be/o9aaoiyJlcM"` is just a static line that I don't have to be re-entering the url, you can change it back to the input if you wish. After assigning the link to the `url` variable I then pass that `url` to a function called `sort_resolutions(url)` where the link will be used and extract all that we will need. I used the function because it just makes the code more organized.

Within the `sort_resolution` function notice where I have created two lists objects... `video_resolutions` and `videos`, `video_resolutions = []`, `videos = []`, I have these populated by the stream objects.

```
for stream in my_video.streams.order_by('resolution'):
    video_resolutions.append(stream.resolution) # Populating the resolution list
    videos.append(stream) # Populating the video list
```

`my_video.streams.order_by('resolution')` this is just sorting the stream objects by resolution in order.

`return video_resolutions, videos` is just returning the lists that has been populated, `video_resolutions, videos = sort_resolutions(url)`.

The values returned is now going to be passed to the `download` function `download(video_resolutions, videos)`. Please note that within this function the `while loop` is to keep a display of the menu on the screen of all the available resolutions that can be downloaded. If the user selects a valid number that `choice` variable collects the value and we will then use `choice - 1` to find that index of the desired resolution by `resolution_to_download = video_resolutions[choice - 1]`, but this will only find the resolution. In order to download the video that matches the same index number in the videos list, you'll have to `videos[choice - 1].download()`. In order words, `videos[choice - 1]` is a stream object so by calling the download method `videos[choice - 1].download()` still works.

One more notice, the resolution list may contain duplication for the resolution. So maybe you can fine tune that.